# Corresponding norm from a dual norm?

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X,N_1)$ be a Banach space (separable if necessary) and let $(X^*,N_1^*)$ be its dual space. Here $N_1^*$ denotes the classical dual norm associated to $N_1$.

Let $N_2^*$ be an equivalent norm to $N_1^*$ on $X^*$. Can we construct a norm $N_2$ on $X$ such that $N_2^*$ is the corresponding dual norm associated to $N_2$?

My idea is the following :

$$ N_2 (x) := \sup_{\substack{f \in X^* \\ N_2^* (f) \leq 1}} \vert f(x) \vert. $$

However, with such a definition of $N_2$, I do not manage to prove that $N_2^*$ is the dual norm associated to $N_2$ ...

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes, your idea will work. Note that $N_1(x)=\sup_{f\in X^*,N_1^*(f)\leq 1}|f(x)|$. Hence, as $N_1^*$ and $N_2^*$ are equivalent, so are $N_1$ and $N_2$. From this it also follows that a linear functional on $X$ is continuous in $N_1$ if and only if it is continuous in $N_2$, so that $(X^*,N_1^*)=(X,N_2)^*$. Now you need to show that the norms are identical.

Comment: Of course, the norm of any $f\in(X,N_2)^*$ is $\sup_{x\in X,N_2(x)\leq 1}|f(x)|$.  Note that if $x\in X$ and $N_2(x)=1$ then $|f(x)|\leq 1$ for any $f\in X^*$ with $N_2^*(f)\leq 1$.  By considering $f/N_2^*(f)$ in place of $f$, this means $|f(x)|\leq N_2^*(f)=N_2^*(f)N_2(x)$ for any $f\in X^*$ and $x\in X$ with $N_2(x)=1$. Hence, the norm on $(X,N_2)^*$ is bounded above by $N_2^*$. Can you show also that it is bounded below by $N_2^*$? If so then you will be done.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in "Calculus without derivatives" of Prof. Jean-Paul Penot. I refer to Lemma 3.94 p.251.

The answer is the following : an equivalent norm on the dual $X^*$ is the dual norm of an equivalent norm on $X$ if and only if it is weak-* lower semicontinuous.

The major idea is the following. Let us consider the notations introduced in the above question.

--> If $N_2^*$ is a norm on $X^*$ equivalent to $N_1^*$, then one can easily prove that $N_2$ is a norm equivalent to $N_1$.

--> Now, let us denote by $\tilde{N}_2$ the dual norm associated to $N_2$. Our aim is to prove that $N_2^* = \tilde{N}_2$. As detailed by @anonymous, one can easily prove that $\tilde{N}_2 \leq N^*_2$.

--> Now, let us assume by contradiction that there exists $f \in X^*$ such that $\tilde{N}_2 (f) < N^*_2 (f)$. Then, there exists $g \in X^*$ such that $0 < \tilde{N}_2 (g) \leq 1 < N^*_2 (g)$. Since $N^*_2$ is weak-* lower semicontinuous, its unit ball B is convex and closed in $X^*$ with the weak-* topology. As a consequence, from the Hahn-Banach separation theorem, we can separate $\{ g \}$ and $B$. Since the dual of $X^*$ (endowed with the weak-* topology) coincides with $X$, we obtain that there exists $x_0 \in X$ such that 
$$ f(x_0) \leq \alpha - \varepsilon < \alpha + \varepsilon \leq g(x_0)$$ for all $f \in B$. In particular, $x_0 \neq 0$. Then, from definition of $N_2$, we get that $$N_2 (x_0) < g(x_0) \leq \tilde{N}_2 (g_0) N_2 (x_0)$$ and we obtain that $\tilde{N}_2 (g_0) > 1$. This is a contradiction.

The conclusion follows.